# Hola, soy nueva programando como puedo graficar un circulo con flechas en mathloplib.pyplot?

Tags: python, spyder

estuve intentando asignar variables .get(), debido a que estaba haciendo un simulador de mcuv, pero
no se como hacer una flechita (-------------->) en el grafico, alguien sabe como hacer una flecha para que aparesca al grafico??
de manera que se relacione con un .get()? me encantaria mejorar en mi programacion
apenas soy nueva pero me esta gustando mucho programar TT

en mathloplib

Comment: Lo que buscas se llaman anotaciones y aquí tienes la documentación https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/text/annotations.html pero no entiendo a qué te refieres con "relacionarlo con un .get()"

Comment: @abulafia omg muchicimas graciassss,    a lo de relacionarlo con un .get() , me referia sobre como se podria relacionar una grafica con valores ya establecidos , por ejemplo ingresas un valor  y en el grafico debe salir el valor, ah y tambien muchicimas gracias estoy muy agradecida :,) igual de todas maneras muchas gracias!!

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.